# Prevent spiders from following is matches URL

Tags: .htaccess

How do I prevent spriders crawling pages that start with mydomain.com/abc...

For example mydomain.com/abcSGGSHS or mydomain.com/abc6bNNha

I think I need to add some sort of regular expression to the web root's .htaccess, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With mod_rewrite enabled, you can do the following

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^YourBadSpiderName [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^AotherBadSpider
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^abc
RewriteRule ^$ http://mydomain.com/404.html [NC,L]
```

You'll have to update the spider names accordingly. If a bot changes his user agent, let's say  to 'Mozilla/Firefox', you're out of luck..